# Android GPS JSON Server

Tags: android, json

I need to create an android application like server style that receives an http request and then sends JSON of the current location, mean that i need to send the long and lat to desktop when requested.

so please guide me through what is the best option to create the server using tcp sockets or what so ever

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/), it may help you. All u have to do is call a URl & parsing the data..